# Use different texture for specific triangles in VBO

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader

I have 9 quads made of triangles, like this:

[image]

I'm using `VBO` to store data about them - their position and textures coordinates.

My question is - is it possible to make the quad 5 to have a different texture than the rest of quads by using only one `VBO` and `shader`? :

[image]

Green color represents texture 1 and yellow - texture 2.

So far I got:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = { 
    // Positions
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    ...

    // Texture coordinates
    0.0f, 0.0f, 
    ...
};
```

I'm creating `VBO` by using that `vertices[]` array, and then I'm binding my first texture `m_texture1` (I also have access to the second one - `m_texture2`) and calling shader:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture1);

glUseProgram(program);

glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, m_vboId);          // for vertex coordinates
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);                                      // Vertices
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*108));           // Texture
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 108);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

glUseProgram(0);
```

My vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texcoord;

out vec2 Texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    Texcoord = texcoord;
}
```

And fragment shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 Texcoord;

out vec4 outputColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    outputColor = texture(tex, Texcoord) * vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
```

So basically I'm using here only that one texture, because I have no idea how could I use  the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using different [texture image units](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Texture_image_units) and setting their values to `uniform sampler2D tex`.

You would have to call [glActiveTexture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glActiveTexture) and set texture image unit (GL_TEXTURE0), bind your green texture, then set active texture to GL_TEXTURE1 and bind your yellow texture. This way your green texture will have texture image unit id 0 and yellow 1.

You would have to split your drawing calls into two: one for green quads and other for yellow.
You will have to set which texture to use by setting your `uniform sampler2D tex` using [glUniform1i](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) for each call.
And finally call `glDrawArrays` for a subset of triangles in your VBO indicating green or yellow ones you are drawing in a current call.

Also you might consider using a [texture atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) if all you need to draw is a picture in your example. In that case you would have a single texture mapped in a single call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To be honest, I have it in one texture, but because I needed different styles for outer and inner texture (GL_REPEAT and GL_CLAMP) I splitted it into two, but maybe it is possible to somehow change those parameters just for inner quad?

Comment: @Mosquito, no in that case use two textures.

Comment: When using multiple draw calls, the obvious thing would be to just switch the texture binding. But with multitexturing (all textures bound in several units), you could as well introduce an additional integer vertex attribute, identifying the texture to be used, which allows to do this using a single draw call.

Comment: @datenwolf Do you know any article online that would help me understand what you just wrote? I know how to use multiple textures (glActiveTexture), for example to blend them together, but I don't know how could I 'locate' the second texture in specific area (my quad in the center) using a single draw call.

Comment: @Mosquito, you would simply add an extra vertex attribute ( in addition to position and texture coordinates) and use it instead of uniform tex.